# Algorithms needed on filtering the noise caused by the vibration

Tags: algorithm, filtering, modeling, signal-processing

For example you measure the data coming from some device, it can be a mass of the object moving on the bridge. Because it is moving the mass will give data which will vibrate in some amplitude depending on the mass of the object. Bigger the mass - bigger the vibrations.
Are there any methods for filtering such kind of noise from that data?
May be using some formulas of vibrations? Have no idea what kind of formulas or algorithms (filters) can be used here. Please suggest anything.
EDIT 2:
Better picture, I just draw it for better understanding:
[image]

Not very good picture. From that graph you can see that the frequency is the same every 
time, but the amplitude chanbges periodically. Something like that I have when there are no objects on the moving road. (conveyer belt). vibrating near zero value.
When the object moves, I there are the same waves with changing amplitude. 
The graph can tell that there may be some force applying to the system and which produces forced occilations. So I am interested in removing such kind of noise. I do not know what force causes such occilations. Soon I hope I will get some data on the non moving road with and without object on it for comparison with moving road case.

Comment: What's the goal?  Are you trying to identify something about the mass?  The bridge?  The other stuff on the bridge?

Comment: A few years ago I developed an embedded system for weighting moving trucks using a load cells arrangement, and had almost the same scenario. If your goal is something like that I could give some details for speeding up the filtering.

Comment: @belisarius: Yes it is related with wighting of moving objects. My data graph has some strange sinusoidal waves changing periodically in amplitude. I suppose it affects the filtering process.

Comment: @mtrw: goal is to estimate the correct weight of a moving object. It can be anything. The bridge with a car is just an example. It can be a moving escalator measuring human body weight or of an object like box. I am interested in accurate data. Actually in filtering the noise caused by vibrations.

Comment: So what's the signal look like when there is an object present?  You need to label the vertical axis.  Can we get the data in text format?  Can you describe more of the physics of what is going on?  You're being very vague, and it makes it difficult to get you better answers.

Comment: That data is *NOT* sinusoidal.  That data is *NOISY*  Very big difference.  Sinusoidal means you could curve fit a sine wave to it.  NOISY means ...  that you cannot.

Comment: @John: It is so if you look closer you will see it. Now it is too noisy and you cant. May be tomorrow I will give better image. Just try to look closer as possible.

Comment: @John: Assume you have a scale under something above which some objects are moving or moving road, and objects are on it. And you measure each time the data of that scale and it is noisy.

Comment: How far away from the weight is the MEAN of the points?

Comment: What's the sampling rate of the system relative to the expected frequency of vibration?  Does the signal path include an anti-alias filter before the digitizer?

Comment: @belisarius: I can say now that the standard deviation of the system when no objects are on the moving road is about +-1kg. If it is loaded, then the deviation depends on the weight. More mass more deviation value. It can be +-10kg. But after applying some filter it can be reduced. But anyway, the noisy sine like waves spoil accurate mass value estimation..

Comment: @mtrw: I don't know about what happens before digirizer. 150 samples per second. What do you mean by : relative to the expected frequency of vibration?

Comment: @maximus ... forget the std deviation by now ... just look at the MEAN. Compare the lecture when you place your load without moving it and the one coming from the mean of the points when the object is moving

Comment: @belisarius: I can't do it soon, I mean test data of moving object and non moving. As soon as I get it I will provide them

Comment: @maximus OK. I keep waiting for it. From the last picture you uploaded seems that the problem is not that tough

Comment: @maximus BTW .. until you are able to measure ... take the MEAN of your points over a 1-2 sec period  and see how close is that to your expected weight

Comment: You may have an aliasing problem. Do you know how your acquisition systems is designed (cutoff frequency of the antialiasing filter, etc)? Check this: http://www.dspguide.com/ch3/2.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in your last plot is basically an amplitude modulated oscillation coming from a function like:

```
 f[x] := 10 * (4 + Sin[x]) * Sin[80 * x]
```

The constants have been chosen to match your plot (using just a rule of thumb)

The Plot of this function is

[image]

That isn't "noise" (although may be some noise is there too), but can be filtered easily.

Let's see your data for the static and moving payloads ....

**Edit**

Based on your response to several comments, and based in my previous experience with weighting devices:

1. You are interfacing the physical world, not just getting input from a mouse and keyboard. It is very important for you understand the device, how it works and how it is designed.
2. You need a calibration procedure. You have to use several master weights to be sure that the device is working properly and linearly in the whole scale, and that the static case is measured much better than your dynamic needs.
3. You'll not be able to predict if you can measure with several loads in the conveyor until you do some experiments and look very carefully at the resulting plots
4. You need to be sure that a load placed anywhere in the conveyor shows the same reading. Or at least you should be able to correlate reading and position.

As I said before, you need a lot of info, and it seems that is not available. I always worked as a team with the engineers designing the device.

Don't hesitate to add more info ...

Comment: Hello! Sorry for a long absence. I've got the data. So, the mean value of the data, when the conveyer is not moving is: 49969,80834
where the true value is 50000gram.

Comment: The way is similar to that plot above, but of course not so ideal and as I realized, it can change its frequency. So if only one object is on the road, then the average of the data when the object is fully loaded (so that the scale is measuring the whole object) is: 49760,93653
But there can be other objects following it placed so that there is some minimum distance between them, it means we can use only limited amount of data. Actually, anyway, I want to find out how to cancel that noise.

Comment: So, if we take mean of the data, at the period when another object is not on the scale, it will be: 48616,79337
This is bad actually. As I know that the "noise" has some vibrations like shown in the plot, I want to know how is it possible to filter it and get rid of vibrations as much as possible. Yes, I agree, it is not the noise, but anyway it makes it hard to calculate an accurate weight. Please, if you want more details about the data, ask me, and I will write it here.

Comment: @Maximus Glad to know you have the data. I've dealt in the past with these problems several times. I suggest 1) Post the characteristics of the physical system (length and material of the conveyor, where the weighting device is located and its type) 2) The calibration procedure you are using 3) a few data series (plots and data) with only one load and with several loads entering sequentially in the conveyor. I am sure we can help.

Comment: @belisarius: 1. Sorry, but I do not know much about the system parameters. 2. what do you mean by calibration? I just get data and have some restrictions on respond, I mean it must be quick and accurate. 3. The data in the case of several load going one after another can not be retrieved for now... Can you tell me in generall form about how you solved this problem please? How the problem was solved in your case? May be I can try the same way, and it may help..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried filters with lowpass characteristics? There are different approaches for smoothing data (i.e. Savitzky-Golay, Gauss, moving average) but often, a simple N-point median filter is already sufficient.

It really depends on what you're after.

Comment: It is not sufficient. There is noise + sinusoidal noise (vibrations)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this book:

[The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/)

You can download it for free. In particular, check chapters 14 and 15.

Answer (score 1):

If the frequency changes with mass and you're trying to measure mass, why not measure the frequency of the oscillations and use that as your primary measure?

Otherwise you need a notch filter which is tunable - figure out the frequency of the "noise" and tune the notch filter to that.

Another book to try is Lyons [Understanding Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dsprelated.com/books/6.php)

Comment: It was first attempt to measure the mass. But then I realized that the noise is actually occilations changing in amplitude as I suppose, when changing the mass. So now I am thinking of measuring or better to say modeling the occilations.. The frequency is not with fixed amplitude even when there are no objects on it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to smooth the signal, I'd average the previous `2 * n` samples where `n` is the maximum expected wavelength of the vibrations.

This should cause most of the noise to be eliminated.

Comment: Averaging produces a very poor low pass filter - you can do a lot better with fewer terms and a properly designed filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some idea of the range of frequencies, you could do a simple average as long as the measurement period were sufficiently long to give you the level of accuracy you want to achieve.  The more wavelengths worth of data you average against, the smaller the ratio of contributed error from a partial wavelength.

I'd suggest first simulating/modeling this in software like Matlab.

Data you'll need to consider:

The expected range of vibration frequencies
The measurement accuracy you want to achieve
The expected range of mass you'll want to measure
The function of mass to vibration amplitude

Comment: I had an idea of modeling the vibration during all this process and use it to cancel the vibrations, but, this seem to fail, because if even I could make a correct model of vibrations, I have to synchronize them so that I can cancel it.. I do not know the way of canceling the vibrations actually..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply the same principles as [noise-cancelling microphones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-canceling_microphone): put two sensors out, then subtract the secondary sensor's (farther away from the good signal source) signal from the primary sensor's (closer to the good signal source) signal.

Obviously, this works best if the "noise" will reach both sensors fairly equally while the "signal" reaches the primary sensor much more strongly.

For things like sound, this is pretty easy to do in the sensor itself, which makes your software a lot easier and more performant. Depending on what you're measuring, this might be easier to do with multiple sets of hardware and doing the cancellation in software.

Comment: Interesting idea, but how is it possible in case of scales? Second scale? I can't understand how this method will work in my case.

Comment: @maximus Honestly, I just misread your question: I saw "vibration", which is practically synonymous with sound, and didn't make the connection that if you were measuring mass, you were probably using scales. My intuition is that this could be made to work even for scales, but a second scale of this size might be impractical. As other answers have pointed out, if the "noise" is predictable, e.g., it's a sine that distorts your measurements by 10%, you can just filter it in software.

Answer (score 0):

If you can characterize the frequency spectra of the unwanted vibration noise, you might be able to synthesize a set of (near) minimum phase notch or band reject filter(s) to allow you to acquire your desired signal at your desired S/N ratio with minimized latency or data set size.

Comment: Can you give more infromation about that? The frequency of vibration changes depending on the weight.

Comment: If the vibration frequency spectra is reliably correlated with the signal (weight), you might even be able to use some spectral analysis of this "noise" to help improve the reliability of your measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering noisy digital signals is straight forward, as previous posters have noted.  There are lots of references.  You have not however stated what your objectives are clearly, so we cannot point you into a good direction.  Are you looking for a single measurement of a single object on a bridge?  [Then see other answers].

Are you monitoring traffic on this bridge and weighing each entity as it passes by?  Then you need to determine when entities are on the sensor and when they are not.  Typically, as long as the sensor's noise floor is significantly lower than the signal you're measuring this can be accomplished by simple thresholding.

Are you trying to measure the vibrations of the bridge caused by other vehicles?  In which case you need either a more expensive sensor if you're having problems doing this, or a clearer measuring objective.

Comment: I want to be able to get the weight of objects while they are moving.

Comment: So, the sensor is on a bridge?  On a road?  On a conveyor belt?  What kind of sensor are you using?  A scale?  What kind of precision do you need?  Are you trying to distinguish between different vehicle types (car/SUV/truck) or objects (apple/banana)?  That will drive the amount of filtering you need.  How much noise is in your sensor?  Does the sensor data sheet characterize the noise/error profile?  Does it scale with the weight of the object, or is it an absolute error?  etc. etc.  What kind of accuracy do you require out of your sensor?  How does that compare to the noise?  etc. etc.

Comment: All John´s questions are relevant ... if the OP cares to answer them and provide zero-charge and sample charge data I am sure we can help on this one

Comment: Yes it is a scale under conveyer belt. I need accuracy about +-250gramm if the load is 50 kg. Noise without filtering when no objects are above - +-1kg. If 50 kg loaded then +-10 kg. The noise is unusual. I made Kalman filtering but even after that I see sinusoidal noise.